# How do I get the current working directory in Net::FTP if its name has a space?

Tags: perl

I'm using Net::FTP to put a file on a remote server. I need to put the file in a folder whose name contains a space character. The cwd() method seems to not like the following arguments and nothing seems to work.

`$ftp->cwd('My Folder')`

`$ftp->cwd('"My Folder"')`

`$ftp->cwd('\"My Folder\"')`

Has anyone done this before? How do I cwd into "My Folder" ?

TIA.

Comment: did you try `$ftp->cwd('My\\ Folder') too?

Comment: What's the error message you are getting (under `$ftp->message`)?

Comment: Enable debugging in the constructor, `Net::FTP->new(..., Debug => 1)` and post the output.

Comment: Thanks @jheddings . turns out I was in the wrong folder to being with ~blush~

Comment: :) happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tried this and it worked fine:

```
$ftp->cwd('My Folder');
```